# Is there an Algorithm that searches for words in an Array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

For example when given a list of ordered words such as dictionary and a 
1D array of letters such as:

```
 A | C | A | T | T | L | E | A | D |
---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----
 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
```

and I would expect an out output of:

```
Index 0, A
Index 1, CAT
Index 1, CATTLE
Index 2, A
Index 5, LEAD
Index 7, A
```

With the index being the index of the array at which the first letter is found, also words can also be found number of times such as letter 'a'. I was thinking along the line taking word in word list then checking checking the first letter in the word alongside the input Array then check the next letter to see if it same until the world is achieved, however I feel this is inefficient and was hoping for clearer method.

Comment: You already describe such an algorithm (which, if I understand it correctly, would work) Do you mean "an *efficient* algorithm"?

Comment: Yes I meant an efficient algorithm

Comment: You can use a hash table based dictionary to check whether a candidate string is a valid word. The algorithm shall still take O (n^2) time because all pairs of start and end indixes shall have to be checked.

Comment: The approach I would follow is to use a Nondeterministic Finite Automaton that I would first build from a dictionary of words.

Comment: An aside to @Tarik's comment: usually, finite automata for pattern matching are not built by hand, but by tools. The patterns/languages to detect/accept are often specified by some form of regular expression.

Comment: @greybeard I am aware of that. However, I was playing with python regular expressions and it was not backtracking in order to match all possible words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following python code illustrates what I thought would be a solution:

```py
import re

words=['A','CAT','CATTLE','AT','LEAD']
exp=words[0]
for i in range(1,len(words)):
    exp=exp+'|'+words[i] 

p = re.compile(exp)
s = 'ACATTLEAD'
p.findall(s)
```

unfortunately, the output is:

```
['A', 'CAT', 'LEAD']
```

CATTLE is missing. I searched around and it seems that any NFA constructed to match all possible words would run in n * m complexity where n is the length of the text we are matching and m is the number of words that we are searching for. Frankly, I have no idea on how to achieve that in Python.

Comment: This seems interesting, is it possible for you rephase this in psedocode as I have no experience in python

Answer (score -1):

There are, but more often than not, for exact matches, the word list is turned into a finite automaton, deterministic or not. With natural languages, things sure get more interesting with number, cases, tenses, pre- and affixes, compound words, …